# iis express remove cache

Tags: asp.net, iis, webforms

I am new to IIS. I made a simple frontend where users can upload a picture. After a user uploads a picture, I get some information out of that picture, then I have a look at that picture manually (for now) and then I try to delete it manually.
The problem is that I can not delete the picture without shutting down IIS Express. It says that some application is using the picture.
Is it that I need to clear the cache? or is there some other problem?

**Note:** I am using MSVS 2015, Web Forms template (I know it is old). This is in testing phase on one laptop right now. It is not deployed anywhere other than my laptop.

Comment: IIS Express does not lock files. So you need to check your own code.

Comment: thanks for making that clear.